# git subcommand with --help arg, not working

Tags: python, argparse, git

Having this example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some Description")
    parser.add_argument('some-arg')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I add this code to file called `git-mycommand`, made it executable and copied it to `/usr/bin`.

Now trying to run command with `--help`, **gives me this unintended output**:

```
user@user:~$ git mycommand --help
No manual entry for git-mycommand
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

If I run command normally without `--help`, It works properly, like:

```
oerp@oerp:~$ git mycommand some_val
Namespace(**{'some-arg': 'some_val'})
```

Or if I dont use it as `git` subcommand and run it directly, like:

```
oerp@oerp:~$ git-mycommand --help
usage: git-mycommand [-h] some-arg

Some Description

positional arguments:
  some-arg

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Does anyone know why custom `git` subcommand does not work properly with `--help` argument? Or maybe there is something else, I need to do, so it would show intended output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git command is receiving the `--help` option, not your subcommand.

> Note that `git --help ...` is identical to `git help ...` because the former is internally converted into the latter.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help

`git help` invokes git-help which opens the man page for the given command.

Comment: The idiomatic Git way is to use -h for usage (which your subcommand receives) and --help for the man page (which Git receives and you have no control over whatsoever). This is how ‘built-in’ Git subcommands work and people will expect your subcommand to work the same way, not that you could override --help even if you wanted to… without recompiling and distributing your own Git!

Comment: Oh, I thought `-h` was just a short for `--help`. Didn't know it can be different thing for `git` (I mean one is used for `git command`, another for `git`).